# getting a Win32 console app to work with MFC

Tags: c++, qt, mfc, visual-studio-2022

I am working on updating/making a GUI for work using Qt. But Qt has to be MFC-compatible to work with our code and I don't understand what that means.

I got Qt set up in Microsoft Visual Studio but use [this "guide"](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/297862/Convert-Win32-Console-Application-to-MFC) to convert and I'm not able to do step 2. I don't know if I'm looking at the wrong file or if I need to modify Visual Studio.

My problem is I just don't know what to do at this point.

Any suggestions, links, or hand-holding?

Comment: ??? Confused.  Qt and MFC are different gui frameworks that can be used with C++. Pick one for a program, not both. Presuming your existing software is really C++, is it a console app, MFC gui app, or Qt app? If it is a win32 console app and you want an MFC gui app, forget about Qt, it has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @AviBerger Qt used to have MFC interop ca. 2 decades ago.

Comment: it was explained to me that MFC was a library..... and that i need "the BCS to be an MFC windows executable." the link i provided was given to me by an employee to see if it works. again I'm new to C++ and oddly enough haven't really set up or used libraries for any code.

Comment: It almost feels as someone is giving you a very strange task. Either you develop an gui using MFC (kind of very old technology know) or you use Qt.. but mixing them is ... well weird. So ask for some very specific requirements... aren't they asking you to refactor an MFC app to Qt (which would make more sense)

Comment: Also if you are new to C++, shouldn't your employer give you a bit more guidance? I mean it also feels strange you have to ask questions here instead of asking your co-workers

Comment: The link is about enabling some use of MFC in a non-gui app. It does not make that app into a gui app.

Comment: `My problem is I just don't know what to do at this point.`, forget what you know about QT, and start working on updating/making a GUI for work using the MFC framework, anything else is a fruitless waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusing wording for sure: when they say Qt must be MIC-compatible, what they mean is that you're not relaying on any Qt GUI code. To interface with the console is a different matter, the console has nothing to do with MFC Win32 GUI code. Your library should be it's own Universe with an API that can be talked to by multiple platforms like Android NDK, UWP, Win32 MFC, etc.

You must in your mind replace Qt with any C++ API. If I use that API, I have to be able to compile it into Microsoft Foundational Classes to make Win32 Desktop app. You will just want to ensure that your C++ code is portable and that sounds to me like it satisfies the constraint. In general you don't mix GUI toolkit. You may want to use the Model-View-Controller model. To get different toolkit to interact you need a mechanism to do that, like a state machine so that MFC can talk to your Qt code. You may also need to use a design pattern like producer-consumer, facade, or adapter pattern to interface Qt and MFC.

If your boss is telling you to make a new MFC Desktop app, in my project management experience this is a crisis situation as trying to convince stake holders what they need when they are invested in antiquated or bottomless pit technologies can be like pulling teeth and may require you to hire an uninterested third-party consultant the stake holder will listen to. I suspect you are maintain an old app, nothing wrong with that.

Please drop a comment bellow with any question and I will update this answer with more specifics.